# Unable to login with email address as the username - WordPress

Tags: login

I just noticed that on my production site users are not able to login using their `usernames (user_login field in wp_users)` that are in an email format. So for example a username like `john.doe` works fine but `john.doe@example.com` returns the following error:

***"Unknown email address. Check again or try your username."***

Email logins `(user_email field in wp_users)` are working fine though. I thought the issue is being caused by ProfilePress or my custom theme. Disabled both but the issue still persists.

Has anyone gone through a similar issue? Please provide insight. I am about to lose my mind because I have already spent hours figuring out the issue. Tried to figure out the code trace and all I could understand is that upon login, both `wp_authenticate_email_password()` and `wp_authenticate_username_password()` are being called! I'm running WordPress 5.4.1 on PHP 7.3.8!

Comment: try deactivating all plugins, and then logging in, some plugins use @ for mentions, so they convert  anything after @ into a link, thinking user is mentioning someone, though your case can be different, try deactivating all plugins, if that doesnt help, please give a img of debug.log to understand what is messing up

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal I see nothing in the error logs. Will check and update after deactivating the plugins. Thanks sir!

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal I figured its an issue with ProfilePress. Once I disable it, the usernames work fine. Any idea what to do?

Comment: This plugin comes with @ mentions, so when you type @gmail or whatever it thinks you are trying to mention a username, therefore the portion after @ is considered as a separate username, and it is doing weird stuff. Would you be fine with turning off @mentions?

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal I figured out the problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Askin Just in general, what was the solution to your problem?

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal there is a stupid option in ProfilePress that says "Allow registered users to be able to login with their email address besides their username.". It does the exact opposite of what it says. Turning it off solved the problem because when I looked at the code, I figured this option messes up with default filters and is calling `wp_authenticate_email_password()` twice in one login call.

Comment: Ok thanks for informing